# My build is stuck in processing and I can't select it for testing in testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

This is what I get in the Activity tab:
[image]

As you can see, I tried to upload a new build (6) to replace the one that is stuck but with no results.

And this is what it's showing when I try to select a version for internl testing:

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you expect us to do. Contact support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed at the vendor's support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually took more time than expected..
So, the solution was to directly call apple support.

Answer (score 1):

Your build need to be processed first. There should be an email send to your iTuneConnect account that your build is ready to be selected and submit to review. It might cost 30 minutes up to 1 hour for that process.

Comment: It's past hours now and it's still processing, while the other other build that I uploaded after it took only minutes to complete.

Comment: It can take days to process. Be patient.